# What is the most efficient way to reverse a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, performance

I'm looking for the most efficient method to reverse a string in Python. While there are several approaches to accomplish this task, I want to know which technique provides the best performance in terms of execution time.

Here's an example of the straightforward approach I've been using:

```
def reverse_string(input_string):
return input_string[::-1]
original_string = "Hello, World!"
reversed_string = reverse_string(original_string)
print(reversed_string)
```

However, I'm curious if there are other techniques or built-in functions that can achieve the same result but with better efficiency. I'm specifically interested in approaches that can handle strings of varying lengths, including very long strings.

Comment: You're guilty of premature optimization.  First, make it work, then test to see if it is fast enough.

Comment: If you are dealing with longer strings, what you are using is the fatest.

Comment: @deceze That old question isn't really about this, though, its title is wrong. They just showed two ways and the question is why they don't see a speed difference (the answer being that their timing, which they didn't even show, was messed up.)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and most idiomatic way to reverse a string in Python is using slicing:

```
s = "Hello, Stack Overflow!"
reversed_s = s[::-1]
print(reversed_s)  # !wolfrevO kcatS ,olleH
```

The syntax `s[start:stop:step]` is the general form, and `s[::-1]` leaves start and stop empty (i.e. it takes the whole string), with a step of -1, which means that it traverses the string one step at a time in the reverse direction.

If you look at Python's intermediate code (see [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bGT7jWbar)), you can also see that slicing is its own operation, so it's pretty much optimized as well.

So, `s[::-1]` is the recommended way to reverse a string in Python because of its combination of efficiency, readability, and idiomatic Python style.

Comment: `s[r]` is faster if you have `r = slice(None, None, -1)` prepared (so it pays off if you want to reverse many short strings). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@xDgIxCIZ3ngJd2precLnFXOLu5OpgHC4nxia9tqFo9OnP9m4xkQEI8P1A@sgjhm6feJ7vHCcUN5ETdFOKLMiUaBCATPJMeEClFOQSt0fyPlo8R/a3zRa41LJ3I@lTDGRx9U1roBIwxhtVTOVL3zftVdma8rW06E2jXuQN3CNjHUUXlph7wGKJXRBdTmFNr8Hr2jLGwP887rBbGSnbJhf0@sCCWFzXmB9RKURLnV1wM89f "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @KellyBundy You are right. I don't know why this does not get optimized, but feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Looks like they [tried](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/86620) to optimize it not long ago but it had issues and didn't get done (yet? I didn't read it all.)